Why is my refrigerator running constantly after the light went out?
My Sanyo SR-S9DN refrigerator shut down due to the light going out. It turned on in 5 hours and now it has been working non-stop for 7 hours, what do you think? Why?

Fridges don't shut off due to a light going out. The light failure could be a symptom of a control board malfunction. Hard to say.

Thanks.It has been working non-stop for 8 hours now. I am afraid that it will break and will not work anymore.

Do you mean that all the lights in the house went out? In other words, there was a power failure or blackout? If so, running for a long time is normal. It takes a long time to cool the contents of a refrigerator when there is a temperature rise.
If you check the user manual that came with your refrigerator, you may see a reference to continuous running (possibly 24 hours) when you first start the new refrigerator.
This will not cause any harm. A refrigerator can run continuously without damage.
